UserInterfaceSizeClass for iPhone SE
I'm working on an app for different devices.. iPhone and iPad...
I'm using @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) private var verticalSizeClass
to manage the orientation of the device...
I am already aware of the fact that it is useless to use both horizontalSizeClass and verticalSizeClass on the iPad as they always return regular / regular regardless of whether the iPad is in landscape or portrait mode but on iPhone this works and by setting verticalSizeClass == .compact
I always get the landscape of all iPhone, but here comes my problem...
I have to assign a padding value when I'm in landscape but not to iPhoneSE and here I can't to find a solution to understand when landscape mode is on iPhoneSE since if i use horizontalSizeClass == .compact it also includes other iPhone models and therefore I won't reach my goal.
So with horizontalSizeClass and verticalSizeClass how can I know if iPhone is an SE or not?

You probably want to base the padding decision on the actual width of the display. This can be measured with a GeometryReader. Then just set your own threshold, below which you show no padding (or less padding). Note that even an iPad may have a very narrow width when split screen is used - the width of ⅓ split screen on an iPad mini is as small as an iPod: 320 points.
